# Send portion of an image to client in PHP

Tags: php, image-processing

Hi I have a huge image on my PHP server, which represents a map in a web game.
I need the client request only to get a small portion of that image. the client request cant load the whole image because:
**1)** it will suffocate the server
**2)** I dont want the client to know how the whole map looks like.

Would **imagecopy** function satisfy my needs? in that case I dont know how to use it... I have this snippet:

```
<?php        
    // Create image instances
    $src = imagecreatefromgif('images\map.gif');
    $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($mapVisibleWidth, $mapVisibleHeight); 

    // Copy
    imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, x, y, mapVisibleWidth, mapVisibleWidth);                

    // Output and free from memory
    header('Content-Type: image/gif');
    imagegif($dest);

    imagedestroy($dest);
    imagedestroy($src);

    ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well, What's the problem in your code ?

Comment: I dont know how to implement that snippet. Would that snippet generate an image in my server? how should I call it from my others php scripts?
If I use require_once the header statement  in it results in none of my page to show...

Comment: You want to show only a part of your image to your client. That's the goal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any large map image or something you have..

But for an example i just searched on google and got a random image which meets your need.

**Step 1 :**

Use the `imagecreatefrompng` to generate image from the `.png` file

```
$srcp = imagecreatefrompng("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/O/f/g/g/S/T/curly-frame-hi.png");
```

You may point to any url that  has a png image

**Step 2 :**

Set the size of the image to be created

```
$destp = imagecreate(150, 150);
```

**Step 3 :**

Make the copy with your custom settings

imagecopyresampled ($destp, $srcp, 0, 0, 8, 8, 150, 150, 8, 8);

**Step 4 :**

Set the header type and generate

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($destp);
```

So your code will be

```
<?php
    $srcp = imagecreatefrompng("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/O/f/g/g/S/T/curly-frame-hi.png");
    $destp = imagecreate(150, 150);
    imagecopyresampled ($destp, $srcp, 0, 0, 8, 8, 150, 150, 8, 8);
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($destp);
?>
```

**Note :**

1. You can follow the same with little modification for other formats, size and image.
2. By this way the user can't even the image path or right click open the full image and yes its secure as you think.

**Update :**

As the OP needs to display the Heading, Title etc.,

As the functions itself create headers and html elements for by default you don't need to worry about it.

But if you want to do it, you can use something like [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), where the php page itself can be loaded in any page you wanted.

Here's he short example of it.

Keep the below file as `source.php`

```
<?php
    $srcp = imagecreatefrompng("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/O/f/g/g/S/T/curly-frame-hi.png");
    $destp = imagecreate(150, 150);
    imagecopyresampled ($destp, $srcp, 0, 0, 8, 8, 150, 150, 8, 8);
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($destp);
?>
```

And Have the page as as `display.html`

You can just make an `iframe` like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Display Viewer</title>
</head>
 <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body,
        html {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        iframe {
            width: 960px;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: none;
        }
    </style>
<body>
<iframe src="source.php" scrolling="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note :** Though iframe is not a good idea, still you the user can't able to see any other part of your image. It means still you're secure :)

Comment: Thanks that code works good... But to insert it into my php page? if I my page was:
<html>
<body>
<h3> Map: </h3>
<Here insert your code above>
</body>
</html>
This doesn show the image.. how would you implement it?